# Cannot exec to a running container

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04

After running docker container,`docker run -d --name nginx nginx`, I cannot use "docker exec", `docker exec nginx echo 123`, on this container.

I'm receiving an error:

```
ERRO[2018-08-19T11:09:10.909894729+03:00] stream copy error: reading from a closed fifo
ERRO[2018-08-19T11:09:10.909988081+03:00] stream copy error: reading from a closed fifo
ERRO[2018-08-19T11:09:10.931102317+03:00] Error running exec 19c6ae3c5d796180e02577f037f6a1bd1453b70393098643719dea3537933ae2 in container: OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:86: executing setns process caused \"exit status 22\"": unknown`
```

OS: ubuntu 14.04
Kernel: 3.13.0-153-generic
Docker: Docker version 18.06.0-ce, build 0ffa825

Docker Info:

`Containers: 1
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 1
Server Version: 18.06.0-ce
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/165536.165536/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 5
 Dirperm1 Supported: false
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: d64c661f1d51c48782c9cec8fda7604785f93587
runc version: 69663f0bd4b60df09991c08812a60108003fa340
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 apparmor
 userns
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-153-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 3.86GiB
Name: **************
ID: OL25:ISXX:RWR7:EY76:OQ6O:XLWG:ETWJ:FV2A:MC6A:ROP7:6DWD:DJX4
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/165536.165536
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false`

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming-related question.  Asking on https://forums.docker.com/ might be a better place to try to get support on a broken Docker installation.

Comment: Not sure this is a broken installation since I can do all the other actions like run, attach, kill , etc.

Answer (score 2):

That can happen when them use ENTRYPOINT instead of CMD. Check your image/container with  "docker inspect". Your commandline argument becomes a CMD of ENTRYPOINT.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact

Comment: This is the default nginx container and it works on other systems.
The CMD on the inspect :

`            "Cmd": [
                "nginx",
                "-g",
                "daemon off;"
            ],`

Answer (score 2):

I could reproduce this issue whenever I executed `docker run -it opensuse/leap` followed by `exit` command. The container is actually stopped after exit command, but still showed running in `docker ps`.

Solution: Restart your docker daemon. And then try running your containers once again. If they stop, they won't show running status.

command: `service docker restart`

This worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your Kernel. Although Docker should work with most Kernel 3.10+ versions, there are often low level issues with older Kernels. See also https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/36084#issuecomment-364886573 for a seemingly same issue with a working solution:

> updated to HWE ( 4.13.0-32-generic) and exec works again, however keep in mind that stock 16.04 uses 4.4.0 kernels - there should some kind of warning (at least) that specific versions combination will not work

Comment: I saw this post, but i wanted to drill down and maybe get better understanding on why it's not working, and to fix it instead of just updating the kernel.
As you said it's should be support on kernels above 3.10, it will be really great if someone can assist with find solution for this specific issue.

Thanks